# Running any functor with half of arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, stdtuple

What am I trying to achieve:
I have the following class Request which has it's own templated function. I'd like to call it with two states:
1) with provided arguments;
2) only with one argument, others should be created as default

```cpp
template <typename TCmd> class Request{
    public:
    Request(TCmd applyingCommand): cmd(applyingCommand){}
    template<typename ...TReplyData> void onSuccess(TReplyData... args){
        //  cmd(true, args...);
    }
    void onFail(){
         // cmd(false) //here I want to create a wrapper, who calls the cmd with false + empty arguments
                       //which should be created by their constructor.
    }
    TCmd cmd;
};
```

Here how I want to use it:

```cpp
auto lambda = [](bool isSucceed, int v, std::vector<uint> vec){
        //doing smth
        qDebug() << "insideLamda" << isSucceed << v << vec;
    };
    std::function<void(bool, int, std::vector<uint>)> fu = lambda;
    Request req(fu);
    req.onSuccess(4, std::vector<uint>{1,2});
    req.onFail();
```

So here is my idea how to implement it, but I stuck on tuples and variadic templates
The point is in creating a following wrapper of function

```cpp
template <typename ...Args> class CmdFu
{
public:
    explicit CmdFu(std::function<void(Args...)> f): m_function(f){
    }
    template <typename ...ProvidedArgs>void call(ProvidedArgs... args){
        m_function(args...);
    }
    template <typename ...ProvidedArgs>void callWithDefault(ProvidedArgs...args){ //here
        auto neededIndecies = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof... (Args)>{};
        size_t sizeOfRemainingIndecies = sizeof... (Args) - sizeof... (args);
        callDefault(neededIndecies, args...);
    }
private:
    template<class T> T create(){
        T t; return t;
    }
     template <typename ...ProvidedArgs, size_t...indecies> void callDefault( std::index_sequence<indecies...>, ProvidedArgs...args){
        auto providedTuple = std::make_tuple(args...);
        auto providedIndecies = std::index_sequence_for<ProvidedArgs...>();
        //Approach #1: I create whole default tuple and somehow applying my provided Tuple to it
        // NeededTuple t;
        // ResultTuple r??
        // std::apply(m_function, r);

        //Aprroach #2: I make std::index_sequence with remaining indexes, like 2,3,4,5 and create remaining tuple
        //then make the resulting tuple with std::tuple_cat
        // also std::apply
    }
    size_t sizeOfNeededIndecies;
    std::function<void(Args...)> m_function;
    using NeededTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

Here are my main problems:
1) How to set my own arguments to default tuple ?
2) How to create index_sequence with starting sizeOfRemainingIndecies ?
3) Is it possible to check the calling signature to avoid runtime crashes inside call()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't wrap in `std::function`, but keep the functor, you might already do

```
auto lambda = [](bool isSucceed, int v = 0, std::vector<uint> vec = {}){
    //doing smth
    qDebug() << "insideLamda" << isSucceed << v << vec;
};
Request req(lambda);
req.onSuccess(4, std::vector<uint>{1,2});
req.onFail();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db9578c69931e2f7)

For `CmdFu` implementation, you might do:

```
template <typename ...Args> class CmdFu
{
public:
    explicit CmdFu(std::function<void(Args...)> f): m_function(f){}

    template <typename ...Ts>
    void call(Ts&&... args){
        m_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename ...Ts>
    void callWithDefault(Ts&&...args)
    {
        callDefaultImpl<sizeof...(Ts)>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)
                                                                - sizeof...(Ts)>{},
                                       std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
private:

    template <std::size_t Offset, size_t...Is, typename ...Ts>
    void callDefaultImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&...args){
        m_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...,
                   std::tuple_element_t<Offset + Is, std::tuple<Args...>>{}...);
    }
    std::function<void(Args...)> m_function;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4efd2b4d902eb034)

> 1) How to set my own arguments to default tuple?

Creating default missing argument is done with:

```
std::tuple_element_t<Offset + Is, std::tuple<Args...>>{}...
```

> 2) How to create index_sequence with starting sizeOfRemainingIndecies ?

You might create regular index sequence and an offset:

```
template <std::size_t Offset, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::index_sequence<(Offset + Is)...>
index_sequence_with_offset(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{ return {}; }
```

> 3) Is it possible to check the calling signature to avoid runtime crashes inside call()?

If signature mismatches, it won't compile, you might use SFINAE to discard the invalid overloads if wanted. There are several syntax possible, for example:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
auto call(Ts&&... args)
-> decltype(m_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...), void())
{
    m_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: In my eyes this is also better than the original idea of the OP as it lets and **makes** the user explicitly specify the default values to use. (I mean, at least from what I can tell - of course I don't know OP's use case better than them)

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t use default values of arguments in lambda. The way I use it would make it too syntax heavy. It will take a lot of arguments and also will be constructed inside a function on a fly. Also I will keep cmd in shared pointers and need the wrapper anyway for other reasons. ( it will be polymorphic approach to keep it on vector)

Comment: @MrBaPHuk: `CmdFu`'s part added too for completeness.

Comment: Offset :0 didn’t know it’s legal and so easy. Thank you! About sfinae I tried to make it through decltype but messed with syntax a bit. It failed on runtime because the whole code is bit more complex. Provided tuple actually made with std::any and virtual non templated class. I’ll try it as soon as I can and commit it as an answer

Comment: everything works fine, though for decltype the m_function should be declared before the template. And special regards for perfect forwarding.